# Why cannot XeLaTeX clip my PSTricks graph plot correctly?

Tags: xetex, pstricks

The following screenshot produced by `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` and the clipping is well done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-func}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\psset{style=gridstyle}
\newpsobject{psGrid}{psgrid}{}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\renewcommand{\pshlabel}[1]{\bfseries\tiny #1}% for x-axis
\renewcommand{\psvlabel}[1]{\bfseries\tiny #1}% for y-axis
\psset{yunit=0.4cm,xunit=0.5cm}
\centering\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-5)(4,15)
    \psGrid
    \psaxes[Dy=2,Dx=2]{<->}(0,0)(-4,-5)(4,15)
    \psset{linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue}
    \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 1,linecolor=red]{-4}{4}    
    \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 1,xShift=1,linestyle=dashed]{-4}{4}    
    \rput[rt](3,12){\textcolor{red}{$f(x)$}}
    \rput[lt](2.5,1){\textcolor{blue}{$g(x)$}}  
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

But the following screenshot produced by `xelatex` and the clipping is bad done

[image]

Why cannot XeLaTeX clip my PSTricks graph plot correctly?

---

**Last edit**: After updating Miktex packages, xelatex clips the graph correctly.

Comment: do you work in a Windows environment? with Miktex?

Comment: sorry I completely missed that. I think there is a problem with miktex on this. I had the same experience a while ago. Herbert knows more but it may be related to `xdvipdfmx`. Your code may run correctly with texlive (on a linux system I would say).

Comment: I get correct output with XeLaTeX on Mac OS X (TeX Live 2010). It does not compile with the 2011 pretest because of a known bug of `xdvipdfmx` which should be already solved for next update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm the problem. Clipping doesn't work with xetex at all in miktex. Even with such a simple example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
abc\begin{pspicture*}(1,1)
\psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture*}abc

\end{document}
```

I don't think that the version of the xdvipdfmx.cfg is the problem. Miktex use the same version as the one on CTAN (Version 0.02 (2010/08/02)). Also the miktex ghostscript isn't responsable either, it doesn't help if I change to gswin32c.

The problem doesn't seem to be new: I can reproduce it in my old miktex 2.7 (xdvipdfmx version is 0.7.3).

Comment: @xport You could use TeXlive instead of MikTeX. The clipping works fine for me, Win 7 with TeXlive 2010.

Comment: @Torbjorn: Can TeXLive and MikTeX get installed on the same machine?

Comment: @xport: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @Torbjorn: they can be installed side by side. I have tried and there is no problem.

Comment: I agree with Ulrike then. A while ago, I thought it was due to xdvipdfmx.cfg even though I could not fix it and then, forgot about it.

Comment: Thank Ulrike for your good answer. Both Herbert's and Ulrike's answers are accepted. But officially I chose Herbert's.

Comment: @Ulrike: it must be a problem with the MiKTeX version of xdvipdfmx. With TeXLive on windows everything is fine.

Comment: @Herbert: Just for cross-checking: Could you sent me your xdv from my example so that I can run xdvipdfmx on it?

Comment: @Ulrike: I sent the xdv and the pdf to your skak adress

Comment: @Herbert It fails with your xdv too. So it looks as if xdvipdfmx or the "conversion command" in dvipdfmx.cfg is the source of the problem. I have made a bug report. Perhaps Christian can find out what's going on.

Comment: @Herbert, @xport: The bug in miktex has been corrected. With the update of xdvipdfmx of today clipping works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any problem with running `xelatex` under TeXLive2010 and Linux. However, here is a shorten variant of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=0pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\psset{yunit=0.4cm,xunit=0.5cm}
\centering\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,15)
    \psaxes[Dy=2,Dx=2,labelFontSize=\bfseries\tiny,mathLabel=false]{<->}(0,0)(-4,-5)(4,15)
    \psset{linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue}
    \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 1,linecolor=red]{-4}{4}    
    \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 1,xShift=1,linestyle=dashed]{-4}{4}    
    \rput[rt](3,12){\textcolor{red}{$f(x)$}}
    \rput[lt](2.5,1){\textcolor{blue}{$g(x)$}}  
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I set `showgrid` explicitly in the `pspicture` then I cannot turn it off globally in the preamble. That's why I define a new `\psGrid` as the temporary grid. But other simplifications are accepted and good. Thanks.