# Multiply defined label warnings when using Subcaption in a Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, warnings, subcaption

In an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-larg), I asked how to create zoomed highlights of a larger image automatically. User Jake provided an excellent solution using TikZ. However, when subcaptions and hyperref are added to the mix, we start getting multiply defined label warnings. Can anyone help diagnose the simplified example below?

When I compile this, I get the warning `Label 'test' multiply defined`.

Code example, courtesy of Jake:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{spy} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}\centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines] 
                \node{\label{test} Testcontent}; 
                \spy on (0,0) in node (0,0); 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Testfigure} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `spy` library will process the content multiple times. In this case this also includes the labels.

Comment: @Jake: I'll replace my code with yours and update my question accordingly.Thanks.

Comment: @Martin: Do you have any thoughts on how to place labels so they don't get processed repeatedly by `spy`? Thanks.

Comment: Even `\def\label#1{}` before the `\spy` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Martin pointed out, using `spy` means the picture gets processed several times, which means the `label` also gets defined several times.

One way to get around this is to keep the spy inside a `scope`, and place the nodes with the `label`s after this scope, e.g. using the `fit` library to place the "`label`"  node on top of the original one.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{spy,fit} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[spy using outlines] 
        \node (testnode) {Testcontent}; 
        \spy[size=1cm,magnification=2] on (0,0) in node at (1.5,1); 
    \end{scope}
    \node [fit=(testnode),inner sep=0pt] {\label{test}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Testfigure} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good on my end. Would it be difficult to integrate this approach into your zoombox code from my previous question? If you don't have time, I'll try to do it in the next few days. Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk: It's already integrated =)