# Pgfplots label get repeated by tikz spy library

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

My question is very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25557/multiply-defined-label-warnings-when-using-subcaption-in-a-tikz-picture) question. I label a certain curve in my plot and magnify a part of that. The `\spy` command repeats the `\label` which causes `multiply defined` label warnings which are annoying.

The solution presented in the linked question does not apply to my example as I have no way of naming a node I can refer to later.

How can I stop `\spy` from repeating the label in a `pgfplot`?

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2, size=1cm,
connect spies}]
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot{x^2 - x +4};\label{plot:curve}
 \end{axis}
\begin{scope}
   \spy[green!30!black,size=1cm] on (3,.85) in node [fill=white] at (4,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

 \ref{plot:curve}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, that's annoying. Maybe there's a way to undefine the `\label` command within the `spy` scope?

Comment: @Jake I think that has been tried in the linked topic with no luck (`\def\label#1{}`). I guess we need to dive deeper into the pgfplots label handeling mechanism...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem happens whenever a `\label` depends on the context of the item which is to be labelled. In this case, `pgfplots` provides its own label functionality. This, in turn, boils down to the standard LaTeX `\label` command eventually.

And the standard LaTeX `\label` results in `\write{....}` (to write something to the `.aux` file).

This `\write` is the "problem", combined with the `spy` libary: the `spy` library collects all its stuff into a TeX box and typesets that twice. A `\write` is also part of that box, and will be executed everytime the box is used (from what I know and see). A solution would be to use `\immediate\write` instead of `\write` in this context.

---

** EDIT: ** this answer was RASH; its suggested solution below might **BREAK** links:
while my analysis above seems to be correct, the proposed solution below is probably of less use than I claimed. When it was later yesterday night, I did not think about the most important question: *why* has someone deferred the write!? Of course, he did so because the label mechanism is used to establish a connection between the labelled item and the reference. Typically, this requires the page number where the labelled item is typeset. And this, in turn, can only be retrieved using deferred write.

Perhaps you can still use my hack for pgfplots because there, you do not want to know the page number - you want to have the small legend image. That should do. However, my hack might (?) break hyperrefs.

But the solution is clearly **wrong** for any other `\label` because it will destroy page number information for larger documents.

Use it on your own risk.

---

You can replace the `\write` functionality temporarily as in the following example - and it will work (for every `\label`, not just for `pgfplots`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\newenvironment{writereplace}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\writeold=\write
    \def\write{\immediate\writeold}%
}{%
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}



\begin{writereplace}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2, size=1cm,
connect spies}]
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot{x^2 - x +4};\label{plot:curve}
 \end{axis}
\begin{scope}
   \spy[green!30!black,size=1cm] on (3,.85) in node [fill=white] at (4,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{writereplace}

 \ref{plot:curve}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my edit for side-effects of my suggested solution.

Comment: It seems that the warnings are still there in my large project with tikz external and so on. I use the labels in the picture caption and they are correct so I choose to ignore them for now. For the MWE your solution seems to work

Comment: Ok... my guess was that it'll work for larger projects as well. Sorry about that.

Comment: No need to apologize, it just means that my MWE is not good enough. I will try to squeeze in some more testing once my current report is out of the way...