# How to place arrows with captions pointing precisely to details inside of a picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
>   [How to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar)

I am a beginner in Latex, trying to use it for an industrial document. I need in one case to use the picture of a device, say looking as a round clock. I am looking at a way to add a number of arrows, pointing inside the picture to points ie the figures indicating 1 am, 3 am 5 am, etc, with the arrows placed approximately radially regarding  the clock. The end of the arrows that would be outside of the picture would need to be associated to a caption...such as "recommended position B of the indicator..". I thought this would be relatively easy to do with tikz, and nodes, but could not figure a way to locate the nodes inside the picture. The tip of the arrows should be located accurately inside the picture, therefore placing them in a mechanical way driven by a diameter and an angle would not work well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the image (the clock in this case) also TikZ-generated? Or is that an external image you are including?

Comment: It is an external .jpg image of piece of equipment. The clock was just a way to illustrate the problem. Try to figure a square .jpg picture of a round clock...

Comment: Have a look at this question then: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "_placing them in a mechanical way driven by a diameter and an angle would **not** work well_" ? If they are not at specific angles how do you want to specify them. I'd be best to show an example of how you want to be able to specify the begin and end point of the arrow.

Comment: Thanks. Borrowing the code from the link below solved my problem. I plan to show a MWE when I am fully done, both for clarifying my initial task, and solving it. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: This is the relevant code borrowed from one example referenced above.                                            \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {%
 \includegraphics[width=4 cm, height= 4cm]{Picture.png}};
 \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
 \node[] (n1) at (0.73,0.45){};
 \node[draw] (n1x) at (1.3, 0.42){\textbf{Pos 1}};
 \draw[<-, ultra thick, red] (n1) -- (n1x);
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}

Comment: The links above provided the answer I was looking for. Thanks to all