# Figure inside figure

Tags: floats

Can I render a figure inside another figure. For example, I want to have a big figure and showing a small one (like for zooming in) instead of the legend.

Can I do that using latex?

Thanks.

Comment: I would do it "outside" with graphic tools and simple put in one figure, that will save you a lot of trouble

Comment: Is this what you have in mind: [Magnifying part of a picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59705/magnifying-part-of-a-picture-similar-to-tikz-spy-library/59710#59710)?

Comment: yes you can, but don't wrap them in separate `figure` environments.  think of this more as "including two graphic objects in the same float environment".

Comment: Related: [Using Overpic and TikZ packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95280/15717) by JLDiaz

Comment: @Alexander, no, I want two different figures, the zooming was just for example. But that's nice, thanks.

Comment: @Assimiz  Thank you for accepting my answer below.  To update you, there is now my `stackengine` package which embodies this kind of logic in commands `\topinset` and `\bottominset`.  They are more convenient than even the what I gave below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I `\llap` the embedded image after setting the large image.  The 2.5in is the vertical rise and the 0.2in is the leftward offset of the embedded image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-1x1}
\centering
\llap{\shortstack{%
        \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}\\
        \rule{0ex}{2.5in}%
      }
  \rule{0.2in}{0ex}}
\caption{This is my embedded figure}
\end{figure}

And text continues\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, my `stackengine` package can do this function directly with the `\stackinset` macro.