# Where can I find the TikZ spy package

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

Where can I find the TikZ `spy` package?
I found a great article here: [How to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar)

Even with Google and StackExchange search I can’t find a site to download the package. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you check the accepted answer on the question you linked to, you will find lines containing `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{spy}`.

Comment: if i try this: `\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}` i get this message: `! I can't find file tikzlibraryspy.code.tex...`. Without `\usetikzlibrary{spy}` tikz works fine.

Comment: You most likely have an outdated PGF/TikZ installation. [You should update your TeX distribution.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/16595)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spy` is a `TiKZ` library not a `package` so it comes with `TiKZ` although its name in CTAN is [`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

As Qrrbrbirlbel explains, you need to first load `Tikz` with `\usepackage{tikz}` and later any `tikzlibrary` with `\usetikzlibrary{spy}`.

You can find some more information abouts tikzlibraries in [List of available TikZ libraries with a short introduction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction)