# Problem with using tikzpicture command in latex zooming the portion

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using windows MiKTeX compiler to run my latex files.
I am trying to zoom and display the zoomed portion as `fig:b`, and the original image as `fig:a`.

I am getting an error below:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/zoomboxarray' and I am go
ing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

for the code which i am testing below:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
zoomboxarray,
zoomboxarray columns=1,
    zoomboxarray rows=1,
    connect zoomboxes,
    zoombox paths/.append style={ultra thin, red} % line width=3pt
]

\node [node image] { \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{disparity1} };
\zoombox[magnification=2]{0.5,0.5}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={red,magnification=5,size=3cm, connect spies}] % circle

\node{ \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{disparity1} };
\spy on (-4,0) in node at (-4,5);
\spy on (4,0) in node at (3,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But, its not giving the desired results.

Comment: You need to add the definitions for the `zoom` stuff as well, probably from this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25433/16967).