# Magnified subfigure without tikz

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I want to create a figure with a magnified subfigure. I know this can be done with `tikz` ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar)) however I want to do it without tikz. Can this be done?

Example:
[image]

My early attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace*{0.5em}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=5cm 0cm 5cm 5cm, clip=true, width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: without TikZ you would be doing exactly the same boxing/unboxing or clipping as TikZ does only without TikZ.

Comment: @percusse Can you provide an example?

Comment: You have the the example in the link no?

Comment: What tag can be put? `{no-tikz-pgf}`? ;-) Note: I removed the `{tikz-pgf}` tag...

Comment: I'm somewhat curious as to why you don't want to use TikZ. Is this a puzzle (i.e. you have a good idea how to do it in TikZ)? Is it because you want to submit your source in some circumstance where TikZ is not allowed? Do you want to avoid learning TikZ? Would some other package like `pstricks` be acceptable? If you can't use TikZ for compatibility reasons, you could use the `standalone` package to create an image that already contains the magnification. Also, the example in the linked question would be easy with `\includegraphics` and basic TeX commands. The dashed diagonal lines are harder.

Comment: Oh, and since you technically didn't exclude this possibility: can we use `pgf`?

Comment: @wrtlprnft Didn't want to use `tikz` because I have never used it before. Couldn't accomplish what I wanted with `\includegraphics` so I used `tikz` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't apply `height` or `width`, you can use `scale` combined with `trim` and `clip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace*{0.5em}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=3,trim=6cm 5cm 6cm 5cm, clip=true,]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use pict2e to draw the lines and rectangles, then overlay all three images.