# How to rotate the magnified subfigures in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, subfloats

How I can modify the solution by @Jake on the following question; I want just to be able to rotate the subfigures for 90 degrees.

[How to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar)

### Edit:

Here is @Jake's whole implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newif\ifblackandwhitecycle
\gdef\patternnumber{0}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    zoombox paths/.style={
        draw=orange,
        very thick
    },
    black and white/.is choice,
    black and white/.default=static,
    black and white/static/.style={ 
        draw=white,   
        zoombox paths/.append style={
            draw=white,
            postaction={
                draw=black,
                loosely dashed
            }
        }
    },
    black and white/static/.code={
        \gdef\patternnumber{1}
    },
    black and white/cycle/.code={
        \blackandwhitecycletrue
        \gdef\patternnumber{1}
    },
    black and white pattern/.is choice,
    black and white pattern/0/.style={},
    black and white pattern/1/.style={    
            draw=white,
            postaction={
                draw=black,
                dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt
            }
    },
    black and white pattern/2/.style={    
            draw=white,
            postaction={
                draw=black,
                dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt
            }
    },
    black and white pattern/3/.style={    
            draw=white,
            postaction={
                draw=black,
                dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt on 1pt off 4pt
            }
    },
    black and white pattern/4/.style={    
            draw=white,
            postaction={
                draw=black,
                dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt on 2 pt off 2pt on 2 pt off 2pt
            }
    },
    zoomboxarray inner gap/.initial=5pt,
    zoomboxarray columns/.initial=2,
    zoomboxarray rows/.initial=2,
    subfigurename/.initial={},
    figurename/.initial={zoombox},
    zoomboxarray/.style={
        execute at begin picture={
            \begin{scope}[
                spy using outlines={%
                    zoombox paths,
                    width=\imagewidth / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns} - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns} - 1) / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns} * \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray inner gap} -\pgflinewidth,
                    height=\imageheight / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray rows} - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray rows} - 1) / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray rows} * \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray inner gap}-\pgflinewidth,
                    magnification=3,
                    every spy on node/.style={
                        zoombox paths
                    },
                    every spy in node/.style={
                        zoombox paths
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        execute at end picture={
            \end{scope}
            \node at (image.north) [anchor=north,inner sep=0pt] {\subcaptionbox{\label{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/figurename}-image}}{\phantomimage}};
            \node at (zoomboxes container.north) [anchor=north,inner sep=0pt] {\subcaptionbox{\label{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/figurename}-zoom}}{\phantomimage}};
     \gdef\patternnumber{0}
        },
        spymargin/.initial=0.5em,
        zoomboxes xshift/.initial=1,
        zoomboxes right/.code=\pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes xshift=1},
        zoomboxes left/.code=\pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes xshift=-1},
        zoomboxes yshift/.initial=0,
        zoomboxes above/.code={
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes yshift=1},
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes xshift=0}
        },
        zoomboxes below/.code={
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes yshift=-1},
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/zoomboxes xshift=0}
        },
        caption margin/.initial=4ex,
    },
    adjust caption spacing/.code={},
    image container/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        at=(image.north),
        anchor=north,
        adjust caption spacing
    },
    zoomboxes container/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        at=(image.north),
        anchor=north,
        name=zoomboxes container,
        xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxes xshift}*(\imagewidth+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spymargin}),
        yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxes yshift}*(\imageheight+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spymargin}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/caption margin}),
        adjust caption spacing
    },
    calculate dimensions/.code={
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{image}{south west} }{\pgfpointanchor{image}{north east} }
        \pgfgetlastxy{\imagewidth}{\imageheight}
        \global\let\imagewidth=\imagewidth
        \global\let\imageheight=\imageheight
        \gdef\columncount{1}
        \gdef\rowcount{1}
        \gdef\zoomboxcount{1}
    },
    image node/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        name=image,
        anchor=south west,
        append after command={
            [calculate dimensions]
            node [image container,subfigurename=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/figurename}-image] {\phantomimage}
            node [zoomboxes container,subfigurename=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/figurename}-zoom] {\phantomimage}
        }
    },
    color code/.style={
        zoombox paths/.append style={draw=#1}
    },
    connect zoomboxes/.style={
    spy connection path={\draw[draw=none,zoombox paths] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}
    },
    help grid code/.code={
        \begin{scope}[
                x={(image.south east)},
                y={(image.north west)},
                font=\footnotesize,
                help lines,
                overlay
            ]
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { 
                \draw(\x/10,0) -- (\x/10,1);
                \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x};
            }
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} {
                \draw(0,\y/10) -- (1,\y/10);                        \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y};
            }
        \end{scope}    
    },
    help grid/.style={
        append after command={
            [help grid code]
        }
    },
}

\newcommand\phantomimage{%
    \phantom{%
        \rule{\imagewidth}{\imageheight}%
    }%
}
\newcommand\zoombox[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[zoombox paths]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{
            (\columncount-1)*(\imagewidth / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns} + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray inner gap} / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns} ) + \pgflinewidth
        }
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{
            (\rowcount-1)*( \imageheight / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray rows} + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray inner gap} / \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray rows} ) + 0.5*\pgflinewidth
        }
        \edef\dospy{\noexpand\spy [
            #1,
            zoombox paths/.append style={
                black and white pattern=\patternnumber
            },
            every spy on node/.append style={#1},
            x=\imagewidth,
            y=\imageheight
        ] on (#2) in node [anchor=north west] at ($(zoomboxes container.north west)+(\xpos pt,-\ypos pt)$);}
        \dospy
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\pgfmathresult{ifthenelse(\columncount==\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns},\rowcount+1,\rowcount)}
        \global\let\rowcount=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\pgfmathresult{ifthenelse(\columncount==\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/zoomboxarray columns},1,\columncount+1)}
        \global\let\columncount=\pgfmathresult
        \ifblackandwhitecycle
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newpatternnumber}{\patternnumber+1}
            \global\edef\patternnumber{\newpatternnumber}
        \fi
    \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    zoomboxarray,black and white=cycle,
]
    \node [image node] { \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{gallery} };
    \zoombox{0.27,0.9}
    \zoombox[color code=red,magnification=6]{0.4,0.83}
    \zoombox{0.42,0.45}
    \zoombox[magnification=5]{0.95,0.52}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The National Gallery of Canada}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    zoomboxarray
]
    \node [image node] { \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{gallery} };
    \zoombox{0.27,0.9}
    \zoombox[color code=red,magnification=6]{0.4,0.83}
    \zoombox{0.42,0.45}
    \zoombox[magnification=5]{0.95,0.52}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The National Gallery of Canada}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example. Otherwise, it is difficult to know how to help you. Depending on the packages and methods used, some optional argument could be  `angle=90` or `rotate=90`, to obtain the rotated image.

Comment: @BambOo , I'm using the whole implementation from answer of @Jake in the link. I don't know if it's OK to copy and paste it here again - I just have my own Figure. I'm receiving the magnified subfigures but now I need to rate them. I already have tried so many times and in several places to write `angle=90` or `rotate=90`but I couldn't find where I should write it to rotate only the subfigures :(

Comment: @BambOo , I added his whole implementation; see my Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with [@Jake's magnificent code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar), but despite some partial successes I gave up. On the other hand, if you only want to rotate some zoomed area, then you just go with section 68.3 of the pgfmanual. (The figure is taken from [@Jake's magnificent code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[spy using outlines={lens={scale=3,rotate=45}, size=4cm, connect spies}]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{gallery}};
  \spy [red] on (-0.9,2) in node at (8,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, this does not look anywhere as nice as @Jake's code, but it is perhaps easier to adjust to your needs.

Comment: I didn't try this option, as I liked and I just took the solution from `Jake`, which one I was trying desperately to understand how to "modify" for my purpose. But, now even this one works fine, just I'm showing a single magnified subfigure, which is still OK. Thank u so much!!!