# Put multiple magnified images in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to number each image as (a), (b).......(i),  (j) but i am unable to do it. I have inserted the magnified images in a table using the following code:
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,red,magnification=5,size=1cm, connect spies}]
\node { \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{gallery} };
\spy on (0.01,0.02) in node [right] at (0.55, 0.68);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your code isn't included in the question as you suggest it should be

Comment: This seems to be very much copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25433/194703. One way of adding texts to the small figures has been provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441996/194703).