# How to place arrays of figures in comparison and zooming in particular parts

Tags: subfloats

I am puzzled in plotting an image similar to the following (presented in the [CARN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08664.pdf) paper),

[image: Pictures in comparison]

I used `subfloat` and cropped images outside LaTeX. I would like to include the left full image and highlight the selection as well. Meantime, I would like to remove the alphabetical letters given by `subfloat`. Finally, I hope to export this full figure as a single `.eps` file for simplicity. Please gimme a hint. Thanks!

Comment: OK, here is a hint. The spy library of Ti*k*Z can achieve these things. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25433/121799

Comment: @marmot I've also noticed `spy`,  but I didn't find this thread. Thanks!

Comment: Does the highlighted section move or is it fixed?  The zoomed images would all have to come from different high-rez versions of the image (which would make the article HUGE).  One might be able to place them all on top of each other and pull off one layer at a time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It is supposed to be fixed when rendered.

Comment: Ah, a much easier problem.  I would align the images and "captions" using a tabular.  You can use standalone.cls to merge everything into one PDF (which can be converted to eps).  One can add the yellow rectangle using tikz.  Actually, you could do the whole thing using tikz, but that is true about almost everything.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Good point!

Answer (score 2):

It can be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering

            \sbox{\bigpicturebox}{%
              \scalebox{1.2}[1.2]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
            }

            \usebox{\bigpicturebox}\hfill
            \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigpicturebox][s]{.45\textwidth}
            \subfigure[a]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
            \subfigure[b]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
            \subfigure[c]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}}

            \vfill

            \subfigure[a]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
            \subfigure[b]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
            \subfigure[c]
            {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
            \end{minipage}

            \caption{Comparison of images}

    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete (small) document.

Comment: It is edited @Zarko