# Subfigures of magnified parts from images without including the whole figures in LaTeX and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, spy

I'm writing a research paper and I would like to compare a portion of the reference image (while including the latter) with the zoom of many portions of images of other methods, but, without including the whole images of the other methods, something exactly like the included picture taken from [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08664.pdf). I found many helpful codes such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar/25433#25433), so far I use the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 [spy using outlines={square,yellow,magnification=2.5,size=1.7cm}] 
 \node {\includegraphics[trim=4cm 4cm 2cm 2cm, clip=true, width=0.2\textwidth]{figures/image.png}}; 
 \spy on (-0.5,0.2) in node [left] at (1.8,-0.97); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it produces an image with a frame around the portion to be zoomed and a zoom of the same portion on the same figure. I'm very new to TikZ and I can't figure out yet how to make my figures look like the ones below. Could anyone help me with this please?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Even if you are new, you can at least show us what you have tried, can't you? The linked post gives you a head start and I do not know where you are struggling. Actually, rereading the post, you do not want to zoom with LaTeX methods, do you? It seems more that you want to include a bunch of little zooms and arrange them in an array.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the post I included produces zoomed subfigures of the same image, what I want to do in to have subfigures of magnifyed portions of many different images while keeping the big reference image on the left just life the image above. Well, the zoom would be ideally done with the ''spy" library from tikz no?

Comment: Not sure why you insist on `spy`. All you need to do is to clip the various different magnifications correctly, put them in a tabular, and add the yellow frame on the bigger picture. `spy` is useful if these are magnifications of the *same* graphics, but this seems to be the case for at most  one of them. And anyone trying to write an answer neither knows your document class not has your graphics.

Comment: Please edit your question, move code snippet from comment to question and extend it complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) , which we can test as it is.  As mentioned @Schrödinger'scat, you not need `spy` library, just add new node positioned relative to node with image.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar