# Overleaf '{' being ignored in \label

Tags: overleaf

I'm try to implement this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25433) to my document. On TexStudio, it works well however on Overleaf it doesn't compile. It complains about inconsistent `{` and `}` after tracing my code I noticed one of my `{` is being ignored see picture below.

[image]

In line 89, the `{` after `\pgfkeysvalueof` is being ignored and causing compilation errors. The same applies in line 90.

Comment: This is because the code checker isn't a full LaTeX parser, so it doesn't know that `\begin{scope}` and `\end{scope}` are actually matched properly based on the usage of the TikZ keys. You can disable code check for portions of code that are problematic: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Paul, I was able to [disable](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file) code checking for the problematic segment of code.