# Generate Magnified Image from each sample image in a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want to make the magnified image arrangements as shown in the attachments for a sample image. But I have no clue how to make such magnified arrangements. Please provide a way to solve this problem.[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtu5U.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar)

Comment: @NBur – Even better!